# I have the error in my code I try all the way but it doesn't work I use flutter downgrade command flutter clean etc

Tags: flutter, gradle

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_staggered_animations-0.1.2/lib/src/animation_configuration.dart:161:20: Error: The method 'ancestorWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorWidgetOfExactType'.
    return context.ancestorWidgetOfExactType(AnimationConfiguration)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_staggered_animations-0.1.2/lib/src/animation_limiter.dart:75:20: Error: The method 'ancestorWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorWidgetOfExactType'.
    return context.ancestorWidgetOfExactType(_AnimationLimiterProvider)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_simple_video_player-0.0.9/lib/flutter_simple_video_player.dart:124:33: Error: No named parameter with the name 'isInitialRoute'.
        settings: RouteSettings(isInitialRoute: false),
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart:520:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const RouteSettings({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_simple_video_player-0.0.9/lib/flutter_simple_video_player.dart:134:17: Error: No named parameter with the name 'resizeToAvoidBottomPadding'.
                resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1451:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const Scaffold({
        ^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 21s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: please share your code